# How to get gstream rtspsrc location uri or name of the element of current frame?

Tags: c++11, gstreamer

I have several rtspsrc source and using in my pipeline to make filter/calculations/object detection.

Is there any way to get current frame name or the rtspsrc location from the c++ to decide to branching the program ?

ie:

rtspsrc location=rtsp:///?h264x=4   name=source_2 message-forward=true
rtspsrc location=rtsp:///?h264x=4   name=source_3 message-forward=true
rtspsrc location=rtsp:///?h264x=4   name=source_4 message-forward=true

I want to get location=...  or the name for current frame in my developed plugin.

Best

Answer (score 0):

To get the element based on a given name is relatively simple. You didn't provide any code to go on, but normally you should have a pointer to the pipeline created somewhere (normally a `GstElement*` or a `GstPipeline*`).

The [`GstPipeline`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gstpipeline.html) class extends the [`GstBin`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gstbin.html) class, which has a method [gst_bin_get_by_name()](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gstbin.html?gi-language=c#gst_bin_get_by_name) to retrieve a pointer to the specific rtspsrc. You can get element properties using [`g_object_get()`](https://docs.gtk.org/gobject/method.Object.get.html) (as `GstElement` implements the `GObject` base class).

Example:

```c
GstElement *pipeline; // you should have a pointer to this element somewhere already

GstElement *rtspsrc = gst_bin_get_by_name (GST_BIN (pipeline), "source2");
if (rtspsrc == null) {
    GST_WARNING ("source2 element doesn't exist!");
    return;
}

char *location = NULL;
g_object_get (rtspsrc, "location", &location, NULL);
GST_INFO ("source2 has location '%s'", location);
free (location);
```

Note that the "name of the frame" doesn't really make sense, since H.264 frames (or video frames in general) don't have a "name".

Comment: I want to get current rtsps location url or given name. My pipe several rtps sources and doing postprocessing  So I need to know the current frame source url / name

Comment: You'll have to specify the rest of your pipeline then, since its structure will decide what which rtspsrc is currently being used